# Keyboard Control on characters made with Adobe CS4 Bone Tool?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

Is there any way to control a character made with Adobe CS4 Bone Tool via keyboard buttons? Its limbs are linked up by IK chains built by Bone Tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import fl.ik.*;

use

IKArmature
IKBone
IKJoint
IKMover

```
addEventListener(keyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);

function keyDownHandler(event:Event){

    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
    {
      // do your magic with IKMover moveTo() method
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes. IKMover works, but it only moves a bit. Seems constraints are set, but I haven't.

Comment: try setting .rotationConstrained on the IKJoint to false or adjusting .rotationMin and .rotationMax

Comment: Ok . It now works. Seems I need some trainings to control my bones.